# Codeigniter, Duplicating Results After Nested Foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got 2 models within my Codeigniter, 1 getting all rooms and the second model is getting the booked rooms in a range of selected date.

On my view I can list all rooms with a foreach and when I insert another foreach for the booked ones to appear in red color, I get a result but, I see duplicated results

My Models:

```
public function rooms(){
    $result = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('rooms')
    ->group_by('room_id')
    ->get()
    ->result();

    return $result;
}


public function check_room_availability($start, $end){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('room_actions as ra', 'rooms as r');
    $this->db->join('rooms as r', 'r.room_id = re.room_id', 'LEFT'); 
    $this->db->where('ra.days >=', $start);
    $this->db->where('ra.days <=', $end); 
    $this->db->group_by('ra.room_id'); 

    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    return $query;
    }
```

And my View :

```
<?php foreach($all_rooms as $room) { 
    foreach($booked_ones as $booked) {?>
  <div class="<?php
      if($booked->room_id == $room->room_id){
        echo 'room_box red';}
        else{
          echo 'room_box green';}?>">

      <?php echo $room->room_id; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

I'd appreaciate if you could help me. Thanks.

As you can see in the image below if I have 2 rooms booked for the chosen dates my rooms duplicate. If I have 3 rooms booked, then it becomes X 3.

https://pasteboard.co/I8AkG8i.jpg

Comment: I think you need only one query to do this no need to write two model function, you need to modify your check_room_availability function

Comment: Add both table's structure. I think this can be done with only one query

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public function check_room_availability($start, $end) {
        $this->db->select('r.room_id as room_id,ra.room_id as booked_room_id');
        $this->db->from('rooms as r');
        $this->db->join('room_actions as ra', 'r.room_id = ra.room_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->where('ra.days >=', $start);
        $this->db->where('ra.days <=', $end);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

OR

```
public function check_room_availability($start, $end) {
        $this->db->select('*,(select room_id from room_actions as ra where ra.room_id = r.room_id and ra.days >=' . $start . ' and ra.days <=' . $end . ') as booked_room_id');
        $this->db->from('rooms as r');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
}
```

To better result please share your tables or your expected output, according to that I can update my query

Comment: Dear @M.Hemant, thank you for your help. However when I try your answer I can say that nothing has changed. And I am adding a screenshot of my problem. I need my rooms appear only once.

Comment: @demyr Please check new query in OR part

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will help you.

If `rooms` table has a unique `room_id` then do not need to use `group_by()`

```
public function rooms(){
$result = $this->db->select('*')
->from('rooms')
->get()
->result();

return $result;
}
```

Here do not need to `join()`

```
public function check_room_availability($start, $end){

$booked_rooms = array(); 

$this->db->select('room_id');
$this->db->from('room_actions as ra');
$this->db->where('ra.days >=', $start);
$this->db->where('ra.days <=', $end); 
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
if(isset($query) && count($query) > 0){
   foreach($query as $row){
    if(!in_array($row->room_id, $booked_rooms)){
       array_push($booked_rooms, $row->room_id);
    }
   }
} 
return $booked_rooms;
}
```

Now you have a simple array of booked room ids. In the view do this with only one `forach()` loop

```
foreach($all_rooms as $room) {
   if(in_array($room->id, $booked_rooms)){
       //Room is booked
   }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Danish Ali, First, thank you for your interest.
Next, when I try your solution I get 2 main erros saying :  "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given;" AND "Undefined variable: booked_rooms". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Both error occurring because `check_room_availability($start, $end)` give no result.

Comment: And the second thing is where you are using foreach loop with `$all_rooms` try to pass `booked_rooms` variable as well.